# jQuery load() page fragment that does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is supposed to happen if I run jQuery's load() function by supplying a page fragment that does not exist? Does it simply load the whole page, or does it load an empty page?

```
$("#a").load("http://www.example.com #non-existing-id");
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/ajax.js#L196-L209. Of course the whole page is always loaded, but if the element cannot be found, nothing is appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/load/ (at section Loading Page Fragments)

> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

Since the element does not exist, nothing gets loaded within `#a`. However, please note that the whole page is still fetched from server.

Comment: Here is set that "jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. " so if the element is not found will be a empty string return and the current content deleted? Also when there is no element for exmaple $("#NoSuchElement").html() the return value is null.

Comment: @gotqn: have a look at the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/ajax.js#L196-L209

Comment: @FelixKling Thaks for the link. It was very interesting for me to look thought this. Correct me if I am wrong, as $("#NoSuchElement").html() will return null, in the function load() when there is no such element again null will be return?

Comment: @gotqn: `$("#NoSuchElement").html()` is never called anywhere in the code. `.find('#NoSuchElement"')` will return an empty jQuery object, which is passed to `self.html(...)`. Since the jQuery object is empty, nothing will happen. `.load` returns a reference to the originally selected element(s).

Comment: @FelixKling As you can see "self = this" and in the "done" function after the ajax request the html() function is used for the self(this) pointer - so if nothing is select from the return HTML, the selector will return NULL and the content of the element will be clear as html(null) does. This is how I understand this from the code, but I am not able to test it at the moment.

Comment: @gotqn: Nope, functions that select elements (like `$`, `.find`, `.closest`, `.next`, etc.) *never* return `null`. They *always* return a jQuery object, which can contain none, one, or multiple elements.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for this man. What I do was just to execute in the browser's console html() function for element that do not exists - it returns null. But I notices the .find() is used after you tell me ;-] Thanks for this.